# Standard way of configuring multiple application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration

We've got many java components running on several machines. Mostly web applications (on tomcat), and some are standalone processes. Historically, each application uses its own way to configure itself: singleton class, or properties file on disk, or application resource file, etc. By configuration I mean String key-value pairs, that affect application behaviour (eg. folder name to store files, or some timeout, and so on).

**Question:** Is there a standard (desirably simple and reliable) way to configure many applications in one place ?

Comment: How are your applications hosted (i.e. on prem or cloud)?  System configuration is always a pain.  In my case I use a centralized AWS S3 file to let any number of apps read from a central location.  It's a JSON file that has sections that are "global" and app specific.

Comment: @stdunbar Hosted on prem. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Depending on how flexible you want to configure your system, whether runtime configuration is important for you or not etc. Spring has tried to have type-safe configurations, but it falls short of runtime usage. I have personally developed a java-ee web app just to manage runtime configurations. Unfortunately it is tested only in wildfly: https://bitbucket.org/marembo2008/khameleon

Answer (score 0):

You could use Redis(distributed key-value store) and write a service to retrieve the configuration entries for the relevant application server there.

Alternatively if you are using Spring Boot 
, you can try [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config)

If you are using CDI, you can try the [DeltaSpike Configuration Mechanism](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html)